# How to filter out StackOverflow answers to remove those with jQuery

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to prevent answers showing as those having jQuery?

Instead of answers with:

```
$('#somerandomelm');
```

I want answers with:

```
document.getElementById('somerandomelm');
```

Comment: `$` doesn't mean it's jQuery for sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107543/what-is-the-symbol-used-for-in-javascript

Comment: If they mention jQuery, I'd like to filter them out. Also, if any answer mentions using a library, or references a URL.

Comment: You'd need to write some sort of regex or conditon then

Comment: Go to your favourite tags and add jquery to the excluded tags.

Comment: _"If they mention jQuery <...> Also, if any answer mentions using a library, or references a URL."_ What's with the hate, man? Besides, good luck getting _any_ (good) answers if you don't want anyone to include _any_ links.

Comment: Obligatory:  [I see you're trying not to use jQuery. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Comment: @Cerbrus - jQuery, while very powerful, is very heavy and hides much of the cool functionality of Javascript. Also - it is most often used for solving very simple use cases where vanilla javascript would be a much better fit.

Comment: Seriously - why 8 downvotes? Just goes to show that every one on StackOverlow uses jQuery instead of vanilla JS.

Comment: @Stevus: if it were still the year 2000, I'd more or less agree. However, jQuery doesn't "hide" anything, and isn't remotely as heavy as you make it put to be.

Comment: a BIG number of my answers have links in them, if only to send the OP to the relevant docpage.... so I don't think filtering ALL links is really something you should do :p

Comment: @Patrice - Would just like to state that in the vast majority of answers I see, a link is just thrown into the post, with no context or how the poster used the information contained at that URL.

Comment: @Stevus might be dependent on the exact tags you navigate. But a LOT of very good answers have at least one link into something. Maybe filtering out SHORT answers with links?

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get with the site's current search will probably be using "-" as in:

[-[jquery] -jquery [javascript]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-[jquery]%20-jquery%20[javascript]) == Not tag:jquery, not text jquery, tag:javascript

Specifically looking for answers: [is:answer -[jquery] -jquery [javascript]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20-[jquery]%20-jquery%20[javascript])

[image]